# Exporting JIRA issues to a flat file

Tags: export, jira

I am looking to find a way, whether through API's or plug-ins, to export all the information captured in a issue creation form in JIRA. The process flow would be for a user to create an issue by filling out the entire form (textboxes, date values etc.) and then when they click create it creates this flat file (e.g. csv file), which is placed in a specific folder. Is there any way of accomplishing this? Any alternative methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about creating the issue in JIRA as usual then using the email about this to tell an external script to download the information from the newly-created issue?

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that, one simple solution:
You could so this easily using [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/16346) by using post function on issue creation transition on the project's workflow. Simple example:

```
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager

# get issue objects
issueManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueManager()
issueFactory = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueFactory()
authenticationContext = ComponentManager.getInstance().getJiraAuthenticationContext()
customFieldManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()
cf_example = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Custom field")
# write to file
key = issue.getKey()
def f = new File('new_issues/'+key)
f.write(issue.getSummary()+","+issue.getFixVersions())
f.write(","+issue.getAffectedVersions()+","+issue.getPriority()",")
f.write(issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf_example))
```